# auth0 role authentication for webapi and winform client

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api, auth0

I am trying to setup a role authentication from winform client to web api service using auth0 [winform](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/wpf-winforms), [server](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-webapi) , [authorization extension](https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension).

From the winform, I can authenticate and get the access_token and its roles (admin)

```
    var auth0 = new Auth0Client(
                  "xxx.au.auth0.com",
                  "1Zf2W81KYrbHJ8MjPYd...");
    var user = auth0.LoginAsync(this);
    access_token = user.Result.IdToken
```

Passing the token on the call to webapi, it can pass `[Authorize]` but not `[Authorize(Roles=admin)]`

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:61758/api/values");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer " + access_token));
```

Look into the function `JsonWebToken.cs\ValidateToken`, I find `payloadData` has only few values but no `roles` at all:

```
{"iss":"https://xxx.au.auth0.com/","sub":"auth0|57e37cc190da2a82c5d6","aud":"2W81KYrbHJ8MjPYd2WVyVrH3","exp":1487259046,"iat":1487223046}
```

Any idea why the roles are disappeared from the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. The problem is the scope (https://auth0.com/docs/scopes).

As default scope is `openid` and the token is including only iss, sub, aud, exp and iat claims. we need to set scope=`openid roles` in order to embed the roles in.

```
var user = auth0.LoginAsync(this, "", "openid roles");
```